# Getting attribute value xml to be used in CSS and rendering using xml

Tags: javascript, css, xml, dom

I have following node in XML document that I am working

```
<picture source="picture1.png"></picture>
<picture source="picture2.png"></picture>
```

and so on.. I have following CSS to render picture

```
picture {

content: url("picture1.png");

}
```

However I do not know the name of the filename prior. And I can't change the way XML data comes and I can only use css to change the display property of this xml data.

Any idea how this can be achived?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you load/get the xml to your front-end?

Comment: @Jorge Hernandez For testing I download the file in my local machine as myfile.xml and i have written css according to how i want to style the node and i open the xml using a brower

Comment: i would like to get the value of the source via CSS and use that value to ass to url